# MWE for Index under Texstudio?

Tags: indexing

I am trying to generate indices but the following MWE and similar ones do not give a pdf with indices in Texstudio.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a sentence indexing the command
\index{Breaking!word}
with the environment\index{abstract}
and the ordinary word `document'\index{Test document}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: You have to run the external  `makeindex`  command to generate the index which then can be processed by LaTeX.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I now found tools -> index, and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: You could answer your own question, it could be useful for future users, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Upon request, I answer my question. What is needed to get the index with TexStudio is to push tools->index before compiling the document. Other Latex-Editors will have similar buttons to run the external makeindex command.